# Help determining if the following are legitimate files

Tags: hacked

I have installed *wordfence* and did a scan and I have the following warnings.  I am not sure if they are left over from a hacking attack last year that *sitelock* have not removed or if they are required.  Appreciate help on how to determine if these are required files or suspicious.[image]

Comment: All these files are not part of WordPress core. Delete them immediately.

Comment: You can also [download core from here](https://wordpress.org/download/releases/) for comparison.

Comment: You got pwned. Deleting them probably won't help.

Comment: THANKS, all files successfully deleted.  Appreciate the advice.